# Lemma 3.4.10 in Terence Tao Analysis I

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

In Terence Tao's Analysis I, Lemma 3.4.10 says:

> Let $X$ be a set. Then, $\{Y :\, \textrm{$Y$ is a subset of $X$} \}$ is a set.

It gives a hint to start with set $\{0,1\}^X$ and apply replacement axiom, replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$

I am not quite sure how it should be proved...

Comment: What you wrote is the proof: after you replace each function from $X$ to $\{0, 1\}$, and replace each function with the set of all elements from $X$ that $f$ maps to $1$, you get all its subsets

Comment: What does the 0 mean in the set {0,1}, why we only consider the functions that map X to 1?

Comment: Elements who are mapped to 0 are not in the subset, so if you want to create the subset $Y$, map its elements to $1$ and the rest to 0

Comment: Would you mind offer an example as I really don't grasp what he writes in this section...

Comment: I was puzzled as I initially thought that this was a way to get Power Set Axiom from the other ZFC axioms!?! But looking at [Terence Tao book](https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf) I understood that he defines the Power Set from maps... I'm safe!